# How to get all tabs details from current browser in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have opened multiple browser windows in google chrome. I want to find all the tab details in the current window browser. ie., no tab details from another browser.

So in my chrome extension, I am getting all the tab details in multiple browser windows.

When I tried, I got the extension window details (ie., popup.html)

Can anyone help me.?

To find all tab details  : -

```
chrome.windows.getAll({ populate: true }, function (windows) {
        for (var i = 0; i < windows.length; ++i) {
            var w = windows[i];
            for (var j = 0; j < w.tabs.length; ++j) {
                var t = w.tabs[j];
                if (isValidTab(t)) {
                    tabs.push(t);
                }
            }

        }
        sendResponse({ tabs: tabs });
    });
```

I tried :

```
chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
        tabs.forEach(function (tab) {
            console.log('Tab ID: ', tab.id);
        });
    });
```

---

### content.js

```
$(document).on("click", "#search_button", function () {
chrome.extension.sendRequest({ type: 'popup' });  
GetAllAvailableTabs(GenerateListOfTabNames);
});

function GetAllAvailableTabs(Callback) {
     chrome.extension.sendRequest({ type: 'get_all_tabs' }, function (response) {
        Callback(response.tabs);
    });
}
```

### background.js

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
    function (request, sender, sendResponse) {

        switch (request.type) {
            case 'get_all_tabs':

                GetAllAvailableTabs(sendResponse, sender.tab.windowId);
                break;
        case 'popup':

            SelectedTabs = [];
            OpenPopupWindow();
            break;
            // code block
        }

    });

var w = null;
function OpenPopupWindow() {
    w = window.open(
        chrome.extension.getURL("html/popup.html"),
        'xxx',
        "width="700",height="700");
}

function GetAllAvailableTabs(sendResponse, windowid) {
    var tabs = [];

    chrome.windows.getAll({ populate: true }, function (windows) {
        for (var i = 0; i < windows.length; ++i) {
            var w = windows[i];
            for (var j = 0; j < w.tabs.length; ++j) {
                var t = w.tabs[j];
                if (isValidTab(t)) {
                    tabs.push(t);
                }
            }

        }
        sendResponse({ tabs: tabs });
    });

}
```

Comment: Both approaches can work so since they don't it looks like you're not telling the entire story: for example if you open your extension's page in a new window manually (using `window.open` or `chrome.windows.create`) then this will be the current window, not the one with the web tabs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am using the window.open method. So how can I get the current browser tab details when I clicked on a chrome extension.

Comment: You can remember the original window's id. If you want an example, show me your window.open call and describe where it runs (e.g. a content script or a background script).

Comment: Thanks, I will update in the question in details (in a minute)

Comment: I have updated the question, plz see

Comment: 1) Do you load `content.js` inside `popup.html`? 2) Your code doesn't use sender.tab.windowId which would be the correct solution I was going to suggest to use with [chrome.windows.get](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-get).